# Cannot pause pool when streaming data with mysql-node

Tags: mysql, node.js, stream, node-mysql

I use node and the [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#streaming-query-rows) package to stream data from node to client.

The idea is,

define a pool, and queries based on the pool.

Then pass the streaming rows to an array.

If that array's length reaches a length, pause the stream, process the rows, send them to client via websockets.

Resume stream. Repeat until no other rows are left.

I am following the examples on the mysql npm page but I get `pool.pause is not a function`

Here is the code

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 100,
  host            : config.host,
  user            : config.user,
  password        : config.password,
  database        : config.database
});

//turn simple queries to promises
const query = (str, ar) => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    pool.query(str, ar, function (error, results, fields) { 
      if (error) {
          return reject(error);
      }
      resolve({results, fields});
    });
  })//promise
}


const userdetails = (ws, data) => {

//do a check, unrelated to streaming
   query('SELECT COUNT(id) as countrows FROM users WHERE category = ? ', [data.category])
  .then((data)=>{  
     if(data.results[0].countrows > 5000){
        // if more than 5000, we stream
        // the following is based on the mysql code found in their page
        // it has no relation to the promise-based query above
        var query = pool.query('SELECT id, name, address, sale, preexisting, amount FROM users WHERE category = ? ', [data.category])

        query.on('result', row => {  
          rowsToProcess.push(row);
          if (rowsToProcess.length >= 100) { 
            pool.pause();
            processRows();
          }
        });

        query.on('end', () => {
          processRows();
        });

       const processRows = (done) => {
         //process some data
         //send them back using websockets  
         ws.send(JSON.stringify({ data })); 
         pool.resume();  
       }
     }
  })
}
```

I dont know if this is related to making a simple query , a promise or using the pool, or anything else. This gives the `TypeError: pool.pause is not a function` and I cannot fix it. Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: use this var query = pool.query('SELECT id, name, address, sale, preexisting, amount FROM users WHERE category = ? ', [data.category]).stream();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution,
I have used this many times:

```
    const mysqlStreamQueryPromise = (queryString, params) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let streamData = connection.query(queryString,params).stream();
            let data = [];
            streamData.on('data', item => {
                streamData.pause();
                data.push(item);
                streamData.resume();
            });
            streamData.on('end', end => {
                return resolve(data);
            });
            streamData.on('error', error => {
                return reject(error);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: OK, it works, at least as an example, I will reform it, to fit my code. 2 questions. 1- Is it ok if I use the connection and the pool in the same file? I will use pool for other simple queries. I dont want any mixing up between pool and connection. 2- You are using a connection , but dont you have to close it somehow, using `connection.end`  I am worried that an open connection may cause troubles. Thanks

Comment: Yes for count queries

use getConnection method to get a new connection and release method to release that connection after the query.
But in my case connection is a global variable which I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
    var pool  = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 100,
        host            : config.host,
        user            : config.user,
        password        : config.password,
        database        : config.database
      });

      //turn simple queries to promises
      const query = (str, ar) => {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          pool.query(str, ar, function (error, results, fields) { 
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            }
            resolve({results, fields});
          });
        })//promise
      }


      const userdetails = (ws, data) => {

      //do a check, unrelated to streaming
         query('SELECT COUNT(id) as countrows FROM users WHERE category = ? ', [data.category])
        .then((data)=>{  
           if(data.results[0].countrows > 5000){
              // if more than 5000, we stream
              // the following is based on the mysql code found in their page
              // it has no relation to the promise-based query above
              var query = pool.query('SELECT id, name, address, sale, preexisting, amount FROM users WHERE category = ? ', [data.category]).stream();

              query.on('result', row => {  
                rowsToProcess.push(row);
                if (rowsToProcess.length >= 100) { 
                  pool.pause();
                  processRows();
                }
              });

              query.on('end', () => {
                processRows();
              });

             const processRows = (done) => {
               //process some data
               //send them back using websockets  
               ws.send(JSON.stringify({ data })); 
               pool.resume();  
             }
           }
        })
      }
```

Comment: Weird, I get  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined` . Also, where did you find the `.stream()` to attach to the query? Is it in the documentation? Maybe I did not see it. Please share. Thanks